# Do dune analytics `creation_traces` data include contracts created by other contracts?

Tags: create2, create, dune

Or do they only check to see for a `to` address to be blank in a transaction.

Does it find all `CREATE`/`CREATE2` opcodes -> meaning an EoA or contract deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems that creation_traces includes all contract creations from EOAs as well as from contracts.

Every entry in creation_traces has a corresponding entry in traces table. In this query, if trace_address is not empty it means it's and internal call to CREATE/CREATE2 from a contract, otherwise it's a direct deployment from an EOA.

```
SELECT ct.block_time, ct.tx_hash, tr.trace_address, tr.type, ct."from", tr.to, ct.address
FROM ethereum.creation_traces AS ct, ethereum.traces AS tr
WHERE ct.block_number > 16500000
AND tr.tx_hash = ct.tx_hash
AND tr.address = ct.address
ORDER BY ct.block_number, tr.tx_index, tr.trace_address
LIMIT 50
```

Example: https://dune.com/queries/2833121/4729239